# get username from login control and store in database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, get

I new to .NET and currently building a website in which registered users can upload there documents and the uploaded documents can be sen by the admin.
i have used a login control to validate the users using stored procedure.
Now i want that when user logs in and upload the document than his name should also b stored in the database(@Cname column), so i am trying to get the username in label from  loginName control

here is the login.aspx page code

```
asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="ValidateUser" BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" Height="256px" Width="536px">
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#284775" Height="34px" Width="100px" />
        <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="X-Large" />
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:Login>    
</asp:Content>
```

i am trying this and geting System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName  error

```
string aa =Convert.ToString(LoginName1);
Label5.text = aa;
```

Login.aspx.cs code is

```
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userId = 0;
            string roles = string.Empty;

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();
                    userId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]);
                    roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
                switch (userId)
                {
                    case -1:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                        break;
                    default:
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), Login1.RememberMeSet, roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

                        if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                        {
                            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                        }
                        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And validate user stored procedure

```
USE [LoginDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Validate_User]    Script Date: 3/10/2016 10:37:39 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--[Validate_User] 'Mudassar', '12345'
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate_User]
    @Username NVARCHAR(20),
    @Password NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @UserId INT, @LastLoginDate DATETIME, @RoleId INT

    SELECT @UserId = UserId, @LastLoginDate = LastLoginDate, @RoleId = RoleId 
    FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username AND [Password] = @Password

    IF @UserId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM UserActivation WHERE UserId = @UserId)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Users
            SET LastLoginDate =  GETDATE()
            WHERE UserId = @UserId

            SELECT @UserId [UserId], 
                    (SELECT RoleName FROM Roles 
                     WHERE RoleId = @RoleId) [Roles] -- User Valid
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT -2 [UserId], '' [Roles]-- User not activated.
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1 [UserId], '' [Roles] -- User invalid.
    END
END
```

How to get username ?? please help

Answer (score 0):

### On the login control

The controls inside the `Login` control can not direct acceded but you need to find them using the FindControl inside that control, eg:

```
TextBox txtUserName = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
```

If you can not see this lines on your Login control

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
```

then you need to convert it and see the `<LayoutTemplate>...</LayoutTemplate>` of it.

### On Other Pages

To get the user informations on other pages use the `Membership.GetUser()` where you can use the `Membership.GetUser().UserName` for the user name

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell.. after login the user gets redirected to home page where he have to upload the document.. ant the solution you provided can not nork on that page as the login control is on login page

Comment: @VarunPanchal Ok, then use the `Membership.GetUser().UserName` I have update my answer

Comment: not working bro !!  Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

Comment: @VarunPanchal you have other bugs... your connection string is wrong... google it

Comment: no my connection string is working fine, i can log in logout .. every thing is working fine user roles etc .. everything . my only problem is that i want to display the username in a label ..

Comment: and so what is this message ? `Unable to connect to SQL Server database` ?

Comment: can you tell me how should i use the code you provided i just wrote label5.text = Membership.GetUser().UserName;

Comment: @VarunPanchal Yes that way

Comment: but when ever i use it . it gives "Unable to connect to SQL Server database" error but if i remove this code that everything works fine

Comment: @VarunPanchal what is the version of your asp.net that runs your site ?

Comment: let me tell you how i wrote your code .. I copy pasted this code in .aspx page  <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> 

 and than I copied other code in aspx.cs page 
Membership.GetUser().UserName
am i doing right ??

Comment: hey i am not in your code u have used the AssociatedControlID = text box .. but i am using login control there is no textbox code present in it ,.,. how can i access the textbox control of login control ??

Comment: thank god i got it working !! 
I used Label5.text = User.Identity.Name;

Thanks Aristos
you helped me alot !!

Comment: @VarunPanchal If any answer help you please vote and accept it.